# Debug hanging multiprocessing script

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have a script which ingests some data and adds it to the database, as well as downloading images to disk, the script calls the `ingest_item()` function over 35 `multiprocess.Pool` processes.

I have lots of logging throughout the script, but after around 1-1.5 days of it running (it has alot to ingest), the log output on the Jenkins job will just stop and hang, and the script will no longer be ingesting data.

I've tried adding more logging to determine where the issue is exactly, but it seems that it stops at a different point each time.

Does anyone know anyway I can make debugging this easier?

side note: I don't think the issue is hardware resources as the server has 64gb of RAM.

```
def run_ingest_item(*args, **kwargs):
    try:
        ingest_item(*args, skip_recent=True, **kwargs)
    except Exception:
        exec_info = ''.join(traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info()))
        logger.error(
            'Failed to ingest item: %s, Exception raised: \n %s',
            args, exec_info
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(35)
    item_ids = get_ids_to_ingest()
    pool.map(run_ingest_item, item_ids)
```

Comment: Could the ingest action itself be slowing down for some reason as more & more data is processed?

Comment: Unlikely, it goes from ~10 lines of logging per second then just suddenly halts. Also no data is really held in memory between the calls (there's no wierd global objects etc). It just downloads stuff, puts in the db then finishes for each item.

Comment: The problem may be the logging system itself. See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#logging

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE I thought that, so i checked the database, records had stopped being added also.